# Does com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper has internal synchronization?

Tags: java, jackson, synchronization

From `ObjectMapper` javadoc, it mentions `ObjectMapper` could be referred as static singleton or inject once and reuse the same instance.

However if I reuse static final `ObjectMapper` instance, will it hit with long lock due to internal synchronization? For example:-

```
public class SomeUtil {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper;

    static{
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    public static <T> T toObject(String json, Class<T> objectClass){

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, objectClass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Exception", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    //surpress default ctor
    private SomeUtils(){}
}
```

Example code above is called by many services, adapters and etc concurrently. Most articles I read emphasise on thread-safety however I could not find satisfactory explanation on long synchronization lock issue. I appreciate for any insights in advance.

Comment: No. Otherwise the documentation wouldn't recommend using a shared singleton.